# Draw shape to alpha channel only

Tags: c#, gdi+

I want to draw a shape to the alpha channel only of my image.  I can use a colour matrix when drawing an image with Graphics.DrawImage(..), as it has a parameter to pass in the ImageAttributes.  Is it possible to do this with the FillEllipse method?  Or would I have to draw it to a separate image, then use DrawImage to apply it to my main image?

Cheers,
Dan.

Comment: If you want a transparent shape on top of your image (while your image is fully visible) you need to draw a seperate image.

Comment: @MrFox - yes, this is what I thought.  I was hoping there was some magical blend command I was missing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like:

```
Graphics g;
g.CompositionMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
```

then fill with:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.White);
```

Comment: That just seems to premultiply white with (100/255), before writing the colour to the image's colour channels.